# Need to get a value id into an input

Tags: css, html, google-maps

I need some help with this code. I'm trying to get the `id="address"` value into the input named `localizacion`, I've tried several thing and still didn't find the correct answer, basically what I need is to get the value that shows `<div id="address">` and get it into the input field.

```js
function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script>
    var a = document.getElementById('address').value;
    document.forms['formula'].elements['localizacion'].value = a;
  </script>
</head>
<div>
  <form>
    <label for="localizacion"><b>Localización </b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="localizacion" style="height: 10px; width: 299px; margin-left: 6px;" disabled><br />
    <label><b>Seleccione su localizacion: </b></label><br>
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
    <div id="infoPanel">
      <b>Marker status:</b>
      <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
      <b>Current position:</b>
      <div id="info"></div>
      <b>Closest matching address:</b>
      <div id="address"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: SCREENSHOT OF WHAT'S THE ISSUE]

Answer (score 0):

You can target your `form-control` class and set it up to be the value of the innerText of the `address`.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
//Update the localizacion box every 0.5 seconds
var a = document.getElementById('address').value;
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].value = a;
}, 500);
```

I got rid of the `<i>` tags. Use CSS instead for the italics. Also removed the `<b>` tags for the `<strong>` tags. Hope this helps. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t1sz1h4/)

```js
function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
 }
 var a = document.getElementById('address').innerText;
 document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].value = a;
//document.forms['formula'].elements['localizacion'].value = a;
```

```css
#markerStatus{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<label for="localizacion"><b>Localización </b></label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="localizacion" style="height: 10px; width: 299px; margin-left: 6px;" disabled><br>
<label><strong>Seleccione su localizacion: </strong></label><br>
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>    
<div id="infoPanel">
<strong>Marker status:</strong>
<div id="markerStatus">Click and drag the marker.</div>
<strong>Current position:</strong>
<div id="info"></div>
<strong>Closest matching address:</strong>
<div id="address">Some Address</div>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Before anything, thanks for your help! I've tried that before and nothing happens, I understand why your code shows 'Some Address' but the thing is that I need to get the value from id="address". In the line <div id="address"></div> that I have it works and shows the text i want, but the issue is when i try to get it in the input.

Comment: I've added a screenshot, what I want is that the text the address is showing, to be shown in the input

Comment: You can maybe add a setInterval function to check every x amount of seconds if there is new text on the address div. check this fiddle I did it with an input box. https://jsfiddle.net/2t1sz1h4/1/ for your case once you click on the map grab that element and send it to the localizacion input

Comment: I've checked your fiddle and that's what I need. But there's a problem, my goal is that the user set his location on the map and to takes the value of the address and put it into the input, the problem is that is not showing anything, nor the first value. By the way, I've tried the function in your fiddle (i think it's great) but since it does not show any initial value, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use

```
var a = document.getElementById('address').innerHTML;
```

to get value of address

```
document.getElementsByName("localizacion")[0].value = a;
```

to set value of localization

```js
var a = document.getElementById('address').innerHTML;
document.getElementsByName("localizacion")[0].value = a;
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" name="localizacion" style="height: 10px; width: 299px; margin-left: 6px;" disabled>

<div id="address">Sample</div>
```

Comment: Before anything, thanks for your help! I tried this and didn't worked.

Comment: I've added a screenshot, what I want is that the text the address is showing, to be shown in the input

Comment: @Kenneth does your address load after some time?

Comment: What it does is that every time that the marker is moved it displays the new address. But it shows instantly it does no loading.

Comment: @Kenneth ,then add above code inside marker draggend callback, ie, whenever u get the address from the geoloaction api

Comment: the above code will not work, because, when its called, there is no address available

Comment: u need to call it in such a way, that it executes, only after it gets the adress from api

Comment: But when it start it has a default address, so it should work putting the default position.